# On the definition of infinity-category

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories

On 8:38 of [Session 9: Masterclass in Condensed Mathematics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZ4ES3vjAw4&t=3107s) an $\infty$-category is defined as a simplicial set $\mathcal{S}$ (i.e a functor $\Delta^{op}\rightarrow Sets$) such that for every horn $\wedge_{i}^{n}\rightarrow \mathcal{S}$ with $1<i<n$ there is at least a lift $\Delta^{n}\rightarrow \mathcal{S}$. As far as I understand, this definition means that there are "multiple ways" of composing morphisms, as opposed to regular categories, in which the lift is unique.  My question regards a somehow dual notion of this. That is, let
$\mathcal{S}$ be a simplicial set such that for every horn $\wedge_{i}^{n}\rightarrow \mathcal{S}$ with $1<i<n$ there is at most a lift $\Delta^{n}\rightarrow \mathcal{S}$. So morphisms are not always composable, but when they are the composition is unique. My questions are the following: Does this concept have a name? Is it of interest? If so, what are its applications?

Comment: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/paracategory ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Partial monoids* (see Definition 2.2) play a useful role in

```
Segal, Graeme
Configuration-spaces and iterated loop-spaces.
Invent. Math. 21 (1973), 213–221.
```